# Longer side of bottom bracket goes toward which side of bike?

Tags: bottom-bracket, preventative-maintenance

I am replacing the bottom bracket bearings on my Schwinn World Sport.

Which side of the bike does the longer side of BB axle go to?  I would assume chain side but just wanted to make sure.

Comment: What do you mean by 'the longer side of crank'? Adding some photos of your situation to your question will help us understand.

Comment: Yep, chain side.

Comment: Could the longer side of the crank mean the longer side of the asymmetric BB axle?

Comment: @Carel is likely to be correct. To the OP, the 'proper' terminology in cycling is drive-side, i.e. the drivetrain side of the bike; the left side is called the non-drive side.

Comment: Thanks to all !